# Android list view : Attempt to invoke virtual method on a null object reference

Tags: android, listview, nullpointerexception

When I create the custom view of each items of the list view, I get a null pointer exception on the current wish that will be added on the list view.

edit : my code was working but it serialized textviews content and the wish pictures id between activities but I decided to use the Wish object in the intent instead and now I get this null pointer error:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class ActivityMainWish extends Activity {

private List<Wish> myWishs = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_wish);

    creerListe();
    creerListeView();
    afficherWishView();
    ajouterWishListe();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_activity_main_wish, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        //fct
        return true;
    }
    if (id ==R.id.action_add_wish){
        startActivity(new Intent(this,ActivityAddWish.class));
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public void creerListe() {
    myWishs.add(new Wish("Voiture", 50000, getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.voiture,null)));
    myWishs.add(new Wish("TV", 5000, getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.tv,null)));
    myWishs.add(new Wish("Smartphone", 500, getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.smarphone, null)));
}

public void creerListeView (){
    //convertire les items en views appropier
    //prend cette liste, le Layout utilise (creer), et la liste d'items a afficher
    ArrayAdapter<Wish> adapter = new MyListAdapter();
    //prend la liste
    ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListViewWishList);
    //configure la liste
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
}

private class MyListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Wish>{
    public MyListAdapter(){
        super(ActivityMainWish.this, R.layout.item_view, myWishs);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View itemView = convertView;
        if (itemView==null)
            itemView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.item_view, parent, false);

        Wish currentWish = myWishs.get(position);

        TextView textView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.TextViewWishListNom);
        textView.setText((currentWish.getNom()));

        TextView prixView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.TextViewWishListPrix);
        prixView.setText(("" + currentWish.getPrix()));

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ImageViewWishListImage);
        imageView.setImageDrawable(currentWish.getImage());

        return itemView;
    }
}
}
```

Wish class :

```
package com.gokhan.mywishlist;

import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;

/**
 * Created by Gokhan on 29/05/2015.
 */
public class Wish {
private String nom;
private float prix;
private Drawable image;

public Wish(String nom, float prix, Drawable image){
    super();
    this.nom = nom;
    this.prix = prix;
    this.image = image;
}

public Wish(){
}

public String getNom (){
    return nom;
}

public float getPrix(){
    return prix;
}

public Drawable getImage(){
    return image;
}

public void setNom(String nom){
    this.nom = nom;
}

public void setPrix(float prix){

    this.prix = prix;
}

public void setImage(Drawable image){
    this.image = image;
}
}
```

main activity layout :

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".ActivityMainWish">

<ListView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/ListViewWishList"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

the item view layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/wishList">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/ImageViewWishListImage"
    android:src="@drawable/voiture"
    android:minWidth="80dp"
    android:minHeight="80dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:maxHeight="80dp"
    android:maxWidth="80dp" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Voiture"
    android:id="@+id/TextViewWishListNom"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:text="50000"
    android:id="@+id/TextViewWishListPrix"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/ImageViewWishListImage"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
```

and here the error

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.gokhan.mywishlist.Wish.getNom()' on a null object reference
        at com.gokhan.mywishlist.ActivityMainWish$CustomArrayAdapter.getView(ActivityMainWish.java:94)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2347)
        at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1270)
        at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1182)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:727)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:463)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
        at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:447)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2615)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2015)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1173)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1379)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1061)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5885)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:550)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Any help and explanation is welcome.

Comment: Haven't you already posted essentially the same question yesterday and even marked an answer? i.e. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30685422/android-studio-attempt-to-invoke-virtual-method-on-a-null-object-reference. This question contains the same error again that was corrected in the answer.

Comment: @dhke its in th same part of the code but the error is not on the same object

Comment: The `getLayoutInflater()` call is still there in **this** question, i.e. the correction suggested yesterday has not been implemented, here.

Comment: @dhke yes sorry, i havent commited the changes yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the error ! i added this in the function "ajouterWishListe()" which add an item to the list, it was adding a null object even if the intent was empty, so when i was calling getNom(), the Wish was null

```
if ((Wish)intent.getSerializableExtra("ADDEDWISH")!= null){
```