# Android ToggleButton provides null object reference

Tags: java, android, wear-os

I'm developing an Android Wear app, and I have a ToggleButton named `fitnessDebugToggle`. It's defined in my manifests and can be referenced by `findViewById`. However, whenever I access it any other way my application crashes.

I'm currently debugging my app on a square Wear device ("Wear Square"), so the following manifest is for a square device.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="me.package.etc.MainActivity"
    tools:deviceIds="wear_square">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:padding="10dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/fitnessDebugText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/fitnessDebugText"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

        <ToggleButton
            android:id="@+id/fitnessDebugToggle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textOff="@string/off"
            android:textOn="@string/on"
            android:layout_below="@+id/fitnessDebugText"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

In my MainActivity class, I'm able to write the following:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    ToggleButton fitnessDebugToggle;
    MainActivity mainActivity;

    public MainActivity() {
        mainActivity = this;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
        // Show view
        super.onCreate(bundle);
        setContentView(R.layout.layout_main);

        // Setup
        fitnessDebugToggle = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.fitnessDebugToggle);
    }
}
```

However right below the `findViewById` call, if I put

```
fitnessDebugToggle.setTransformationMethod(null);
```

it crashes with part of the stack trace being

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ToggleButton.setTransformationMethod(android.text.method.TransformationMethod)' on a null object reference

at the line I added the `setTransformationMethod` call.

I have looked at the question [Android studio “ Attempt to invoke virtual method on a null object reference”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30685422/android-studio-attempt-to-invoke-virtual-method-on-a-null-object-reference) however that deals with a NullPointerException on the `findViewById` call, not uponfurther  calls. My package name has also been changed in this example.

---

Regarding comments:

- If I comment out `setTransformationMethod` and add a `setOnCheckedChangeListener` call, it crashes as well with a similar stack trace.
- Changing the ToggleButton's default state to false still produced a crash, same reason as before.
- In my layout XMLs, changing the context to ".MainActivity" still crashed with the same reason as before.

Comment: Actually the NPE should have been occur right at fitnessDebugToggle = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.fitnessDebugToggle); when Null is cast to ToggleButton. Were you able to access other fields in the layout ?

Comment: @NaveenAechan Nope, sadly. I commented out setTransformationMethod and let it run down to a setOnCheckedChangeListener. It crashed as well, with the trace changed to `void android.widget.ToggleButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(android.widget.CompoundButton$OnCheckedChangeListener`.

Comment: check your layout name is correct. Is it activity_main.xml or layout_main.xml. If it is activity_main then change  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

Comment: @JinuPC As far as I can tell the name is correct. I did rename them earlier, however after using grep on the source directory it looks that everything has been changed.

Comment: try this am not sure change the tools:context as tools:context=".MainActivity"

Comment: @JinuPC Thank you for the suggestion, but it still produced the same error.

Comment: Check you import android.R if it is there remove it and import you gen R package

Comment: @JinuPC I deleted my R package, however I don't need to import it as Android Studio should handle that aspect there. It still crashed, however :/

Comment: am done sorry man :)

Comment: Try cleaning the project from Project -> Clean and build it again.

Comment: @JinuPC Thanks for the suggestion, but still no luck.

Answer (score 1):

you can use null only in one scenario like this try if else

```
if(checked){
            button.setTransformationMethod(null);
        }else {
            button.setTransformationMethod(new PasswordTransformationMethod());

        }
```

Comment: In the desktop app, I used null without if/else and was able to do it just fine, without it crashing.

Comment: android:checked="false"   in toggle xml and see as a hardcore

Comment: I added `android:checked="false"` in both rect and round layout xmls, and it still crashed. I'm not sure what you meant by hardcore, can you please elaborate?

Comment: i tested your code works fine 
so check these spots and see if any miss match 
>   tools:context="me.package.etc.MainActivity"
or
>    setContentView(R.layout.layout_main);

may be ur devise needs a special define 
https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/ui/layouts.html

Comment: In my layout, I have specified those special defines. The one provided in my question is the rect/square layout.

Answer (score 0):

if you rename the xml file the try this option of android studio :

```
File -> Invalidate Catches/Restart
```

Then even problem occures the change ToggleButton id in xml and check is there java file gives error ? if yes then the id is perfectly integrated and updated in R.java.

Then change onCreate methos as :

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.layout_main);
    }
```

Comment: I'm afraid that didn't work, but thank you for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

I experienced a problem with `findViewById` returning null for all the elements of my layout. In the end, it was solved by just rebuilding the project.
Very annoying problem.